# SQL Server 2014 JDBC Drivers needed for IBM Maximo 7.5 / Websphere Installation

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, websphere, sql-server-2014, maximo

Virgin post, please be gentle. :)

First of all,
I'm not even sure if this is the correct forum.

TLDR: 
My mission is to set up Maximo 7.5 with IBM Websphere / Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
And I need the SQL Server 2014 JDBC Drivers

--

As above, during the installations,
Websphere / SQL Server 2014 installed fine.

However Maximo threw me this error at the end of the 2 hour-long installation:

```
 "CTGIN2471E: An error occurred while trying to start the Application Server."
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
SEVERE: EXIT Exception caught while trying to register new JDBC Driver.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Throwable occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:77)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.database.ACfgDatabase.registerDriver(ACfgDatabase.java:785)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.database.SQLServer.<init>(SQLServer.java:347)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.database.SQLServer.getInstance(SQLServer.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.DatabaseConfigFactory.getInstance(DatabaseConfigFactory.java:95)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.DatabaseConfigFactory.getInstance(DatabaseConfigFactory.java:50)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.TaskRunner.getConfigurationStep(TaskRunner.java:645)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.config.TaskRunner.addTask(TaskRunner.java:234)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.foundation.ccmdb.FndConfigurationAction.uninstall(FndConfigurationAction.java:1421)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.CustomAction.j(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.CustomAction.uninstall(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGbx.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Uninstaller.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Uninstaller.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Uninstaller.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.UninstallProgressAction.n(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.ProgressPanelAction$1.run(DashoA10*..)
```

I tried downloading and pasting the Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server jars in every Maximo installation "lib" folder I could find (during Maximo installation).
But it did not solve the issue.

Do I have to wait for IBM to release a patch? Or is this issue on the Microsoft side?

Answer (score 0):

For maximo 7.x: sqljdbc.jar is already included in the following folder: c:\IBM\SMP\maximo\applications\maximo\lib

I would stick with Windows Server 2008 (64-bit) and SQL Server 2008 based on IBM's [recommendations](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Version%207.5.0.5?section=db). Newer versions may be unsupported and likely has more gotchas.

Even installing a Maximo demo installation running Windows, WebSphere, and DB2 requires a lot of patience. Your SQL Server install, while standard, requires even more configuration and patience. I suggest you work with IBM if you have a support contract.

Comment: 안녕하세요.

Thank you for your reply. I tried Maximo 7.5 with SQL Server 2012 and even though it did take half a day, there were no problems.

I guess 2014 is too new, will wait for new updates from either side. Thank you again.